# My PS3 controller always comes on as controller #2, even though it's the only controller.

Tags: ps3, controllers

I recently bought a PS3 and whenever I turn it on, even with the controller, the controller always starts up as #2.  This is hugely annoying as (for example) inFamous can only be controlled using controller #1.  I have to manually change the controller over to #1 once I get into the game.

Because it's likely part of the problem, I should mention that I also have a USB IR receiver (built for the PS3) also plugged in, so that I can use my universal remote for things like BluRays and Netflix.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging the receiver and seeing if you still get this issue?

Comment: Just did that, and the controller does start up as #1.  Don't know if it'll do it again though.

Comment: I would guess your receiver is acting as a controller input, and since it's wired it's the first thing that's detected on power-up.  Try manually setting IT to a different controller?

Comment: How do you turn on your PS3? Do you use a power button on the unit, or do you press the Playstation button on the controller? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @YellowMegaMan: As I said in the question, I've turned my PS3 on with the controller and it still comes up as #2.

Comment: I used to have this issue until a while ago (with a IR receiver and/or wired controller). However this stopped some time ago, now if I turn on the system with a wireless controller it'll always be controller 1. It's possible Sony plugged this issue since this Q was posted.

Comment: @JohnoBoy: Personally, it's not too much of a concern anymore.  This IR receiver was simply a cheaper alternative to the Logitech Harmony BT adapter, but given its limited functionality and the problem posed above, I caved and bought the adapter.

Comment: I thought this was worth mentioning nonetheless for future readers of the site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controllers plugged in via USB are always #1 after the start. It not only annoying with you remote receiver but also with several arcade fight sticks.

Comment: If this is the case, than Sony needs to fix it.  At least give us an option to set the default controller number for USB connected controllers.

Comment: Sony assumes that your charging the control while you play, most likely.

Comment: @SimonSheehan: If they want me to be charging my controller while I play, then they should have given me a longer USB cable.

Comment: Indeed. I actually use an extension for my USB, so I can sit up to 10 feet away and use it.